# Android Snackbar textsize too big

Tags: android, android-snackbar

I'm trying to change Snackbar text size, because I want it to be easy readable for users with low vision. I write this method to create Snackbar

```
private Snackbar getSnackbar(int msgId) {
    final Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(
            mView,
            msgId,
            Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
    final View view = snackbar.getView();
    final TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.support.design.R.id.snackbar_text);
    tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.snackbar_textsize));
    return snackbar;
}
```

And corresponding `dimens.xml` is:

```
<resources>
    <dimen name="header_date_font_size">16sp</dimen>
    <dimen name="snackbar_textsize">16sp</dimen>
</resources>
```

Here is screenshot of resulting Snackbar.

[image]

Why text is so big? I was expecting that it would be usual 16sp size, as it is everywhere in my application.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`getDimension()` returns the value of a resource that has its dimension scaling factor already applied.

So if the resource is specified in `sp`, then the return value is the number of actual pixels in size.

But you're feeding that value into `setText()` and saying that the measurement is in `sp`, when it is actually in pixels.  So it's applying *another* scaling factor.

Instead, just say:

```
tv.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.snackbar_textsize));
```